# jQuery was not called:Https Configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a json file with data. I am trying to access it through ajax call. i am accessing the script in the https website. I am getting the following error.

```
Error: jQuery110204653455846038177_1518073501526 was not called
at Function.error (https://sitename/news/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js?v=1:21:4112)
at l.jsonp.n.dataTypes.(anonymous function).n.converters.script json (https://stat.sitename.com/news/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js?v=1:23:17176)
at On (https://stat.sitename.com/news/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js?v=1:23:15599)
at k (https://stat.sitename.com/news/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js?v=1:23:13940)
at HTMLScriptElement.n.onload.n.onreadystatechange (https://stat.sitename.com/news/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js?v=1:23:16467).
```

If I use the same script in an http website, there is no issue.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "data.json", 
        data: {}, 
        dataType: 'jsonp', 
        success: function (e) {
            alert();
            },
            error: function (e, l, s) { 
            console.log(s) 
            }
    });
```

Comment: change your question title dude...

Comment: For starters, use the uncompressed development version of jQuery instead of the .min.js version you're using now. At least then the stack trace will show you real symbols.

Comment: Check this guide on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting questions. Without the **data.json** response there's no way to reproduce you issue / help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use getJSON instead $.ajax with JSONP or change dataType from "jsonp" to "json". JSONP is a technique that allows you to transfer JSON data across multiple domains.

```
$.getJSON('/data.json',{}, function(data) {
     console.log(data);
});
```

And here part of jQuery 1.2 documentation:
[image]

If you have problem with origins, you should modify serwer configuration. Add custom headers to `.htaccess` or modify server headers in a different way(apache virtual host configuration for example):

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:80/"
```

After this modification you'll be able to download this file from external serwer.

Comment: I tried doing this way but when I try to access the json file, I am getting Failed to load "https://www.sitename.com/data.json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: There is a problem with your server. Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to your server configuration